# Can I put more than 8GB of Ram in a MacBook Pro 5.1

Tags: macbook-pro, memory

I have a 5.1 MacBook Pro (5.1 Model Late 2008) with 4GB of Ram. All the apple documentation I can find that the maximum supported for this model is 8GB of RAM (2 x 4GB). Has anyone tried to put bigger DIMMs into one to see if they would work? Given the price of RAM at the moment I would go for 2 x 8GB if I knew it would work.

Comment: I'm seriously wondering why you need so much RAM? Most programs don't even use/support that amout of RAM.

Comment: @Michiel - you obviously don't use a lot of VMs/heavily multitask. I have 8 GB in my MBP, and regularly get down to ~400 MB free.

Comment: Ok, I stand corrected. Didn't now you were using VMs :) It's worth the investment in this case :)

Comment: @Michiel: I'm a developer running with a Linux VM and several database platforms. 4GB is entry level to me.

Comment: @MyOtherMe, forget what I said. You need as much RAM as you can get!

Comment: @Michiel Xcode 4 alone needs 8 GB if you are doing non-trivial projects and don't have an SSD.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your Macbook Pro supports only 8GB (15'') or 6GB (17'') of RAM.

Apple states that it's 4GB, but **OWC** continuously check the max. supported RAM.

See this list [here](http://eshop.macsales.com/memory/maxram).

[image]

Comment: For anyone interested I went with 8GB or regular Kingston Ram running at 1333. Worked fine despite the original spec saying it needs 1066

Comment: I have mine in the exact some setup... be sure you zap the PRAM after you install them.