# Macbook Pro (5.1 Model Late 2008) 16GB RAM upgrade

Tags: macbook-pro, memory

Can I add 16GB of RAM in my MacBook Pro (5.1 model, late 2008) running at 1333 DIMMs?

Answer (score 2):

The Late 2008 MacBook Pro's can only address:

- 6.0GB for the 17" model
- 8.0GB for the 15" model

The information is based on personal experience and backed by [MacTracker](http://www.mactracker.ca)

Comment: Thanks Kevin. I was interested in finding out if the person who also answered at the bottom of this message chat actually installed 8GB. I wanted to clarify if it was 16GB total? I have 8GB installed currently. See the link below http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/34304/can-i-put-more-than-8gb-of-ram-in-a-macbook-pro-5-1

Comment: You could put 16GB into it, but it will only be able to address/use 8GB.

Comment: Makes Since! I was hopping for some hacking miracle... Thanks again for the help.

Comment: It's a hardware limitation, so there's really nothing we can do about it. If you want to put some speed in your old MacBook a SSD is probably a smarter choice than RAM anyways.

Comment: This answer should cite an authoritative source for those specs.

Comment: @DanJ - i have updated the anwser accordingly.